# Cumulative sum base on the value of different columns in the same row of a dataframe (avoiding loops)

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr, apply

I have a dataframe containing hundreds of thousands rows, but it can be exemplified as here below:

```
> mydata
  ID TYPE HEIGHT WEIGHT
1 20    6    194   77.1
2 20    2    175   63.5
3 20    6    197   59.6
4 20    1    185   74.3
5 20    1    162   94.4
6 21    1    188   58.9
7 21    6    182   81.2
8 21    6    169   82.8
9 21    2    151   78.5
```

here's the code to reproduce it:

```
mydata <- data.frame(ID=c(20,20,20,20,20,21,21,21,21), 
                     TYPE=(c(6,2,6,1,1,1,6,6,2)), 
                     HEIGHT=c(194,175,197,185,162,188,182,169,151), 
                     WEIGHT=c(77.1,63.5,59.6,74.3,94.4,58.9,81.2,82.8,78.5))
```

What I need to do is: for each `ID`, calculate the sum of the `WEIGHTS` by `TYPE`, **but only for those elements (in the same ID) that have a `HEIGHT` higher** than the one contained in the current row.

The new dataframe should then contain three more columns (one for each `TYPE`), and should eventually look like this:

```
> mydata_new
  ID TYPE HEIGHT WEIGHT SUM.W.TYPE6 SUM.W.TYPE2 SUM.W.TYPE1
1 20    6    194   77.1        59.6         0.0         0.0
2 20    2    175   63.5       136.7         0.0        74.3
3 20    6    197   59.6         0.0         0.0         0.0
4 20    1    185   74.3       136.7         0.0         0.0
5 20    1    162   94.4       136.7        63.5        74.3
6 21    1    188   58.9         0.0         0.0         0.0
7 21    6    182   81.2         0.0         0.0        58.9
8 21    6    169   82.8        81.2         0.0        59.9
9 21    2    151   78.5       164.0         0.0        58.9
```

If possible, I would like to avoid to go through each row with a loop, as given my extensive dataset, it would take too long. Any smart solution? Perhaps using some suitable packages such as `dplyr`, `data.table`, or simply using `apply` or `sapply`?

I want to understand how to create a cumulative sum which is based on the value in different columns of the same row, but is also dependent on separate groupings (i.e. `TYPE`).

Comment: Is it possible to have two heights that are equal for the same `ID`?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. In that case, if they are the only two elements in the same `ID` and have the same `TYPE`, their SUM.W.TYPE would be simply 0.0, because there are no other elements with the same `TYPE` with higher height

Comment: Why is there an entry in row 5 for `SUM.W.TYPE2`?

Comment: Because within the same `ID` the element in row 2 (which is a TYPE 2) has a height which is higher than the element TYPE 1 in row 5. Thus `SUM.W.TYPE2` reports the `WEIGHT` of the TYPE 2 element.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced this is an exact duplicate of this question. I'm going to post an approach in the next comment. Obviously, the formatting is going to be ugly...but I can't post an answer.

Comment: `sapply(c(1, 2, 6), function(y) 
    apply(mydata, 1, function(x, TYPE = y) 
    sum(ifelse(mydata[mydata$ID == x[1] & mydata$TYPE == TYPE,]$HEIGHT > x[3],
           mydata[mydata$ID == x[1] & mydata$TYPE == TYPE,]$WEIGHT, 
           0)))
)`

Comment: Thanks @bouncyball !! I will have to modify it a bit for my complete dataset (which includes more variables) but your approach works and it is quite efficient! Its a shame that they marked the question as duplicate...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121355/discussion-between-bouncyball-and-refroll).

Comment: @akrun I don't believe this to be a dupe (at least not of the linked question).  The linked question is conditional on previous values whereas this one is conditional on another column.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor  Okay, I opened it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the OP, a cumulative sum works here:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)

ut = sort(unique(mydata$TYPE))
mydata[order(-HEIGHT), paste0("sum_",ut) :=  lapply(ut, 
  function(x) shift(cumsum( WEIGHT*(TYPE==x) ), fill=0) 
), by=ID]

   ID TYPE HEIGHT WEIGHT sum_1 sum_2 sum_6
1: 20    6    194   77.1   0.0   0.0  59.6
2: 20    2    175   63.5  74.3   0.0 136.7
3: 20    6    197   59.6   0.0   0.0   0.0
4: 20    1    185   74.3   0.0   0.0 136.7
5: 20    1    162   94.4  74.3  63.5 136.7
6: 21    1    188   58.9   0.0   0.0   0.0
7: 21    6    182   81.2  58.9   0.0   0.0
8: 21    6    169   82.8  58.9   0.0  81.2
9: 21    2    151   78.5  58.9   0.0 164.0
```

---

**Repeating height measurements.** So far, this only works if all heights are distinct within each ID (as in the OP's current example). The OP mentioned in a comment that heights may repeat, however. Thanks to @DeanMacGregor, here's an extension for that case:

```
# run the code above, and then...
mydata[order(-HEIGHT), paste0('sum_',ut) := 
  .SD[.N]
, by=.(ID,TYPE,HEIGHT), .SDcols=paste0('sum_',ut)]
```

Or do it in one `by` step:

```
ut = sort(unique(mydata$TYPE))
mydata[order(-HEIGHT), paste0("sum_",ut) := {
  sd = lapply(ut, function(x) shift(cumsum( WEIGHT*(TYPE==x) ), fill=0))
  setDT(sd)[, .SD[1L], by=.(HEIGHT,TYPE)][, c("HEIGHT","TYPE") := NULL]
}, by=ID]
```

Comment: Well I thought @Arun crushed it but this only takes 0.148 and it doesn't require switching to the devel version.

Comment: There's one flaw in this.  OP said sometimes there can be same ID, HEIGHT combos and with using the `order` methodology it will include instances where the HEIGHT is the same when it should be excluded.

Comment: @Dean Oh, that's what I get for not paying attn to comments. OP should edit those things into the post. Maybe if I add a `*!duplicated(HEIGHT)` to the condition in the cumsum it would do it? I'm not really clear on the example + desired output for that extension...

Comment: Oh, I get it, so it should only sum heights strictly greater than the current height... hm, not sure this approach can be extended to that... maybe with `!duplicated(HEIGHT, fromLast=TRUE)`...? No, not that either. Might delete if the OP updates and I can't think of an extension.

Comment: Actually it's an easy fix.  Just add this line after what you already have.... `mydata[,(paste0('sum_',ut)):=lapply(.SD,min),by=c('ID','TYPE','HEIGHT'),.SDcols=paste0('sum_',ut)]`

Comment: @Dean Thanks; I definitely was barking up the wrong tree. I edited your approach a little bit, but I think it does the same thing...? Also added another way, but I'm not sure if it's right.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative `data.table` solution.

```
mydata[, c(.SD, setNames(lapply(sort(unique(TYPE)), 
                         function(type) apply(outer(HEIGHT, HEIGHT, "<"), 1, 
                                        function(higher) sum(WEIGHT[TYPE == type & higher]))), 
                paste0("SUM.W.TYPE", sort(unique(TYPE))))), ID]

#    ID TYPE HEIGHT WEIGHT SUM.W.TYPE1 SUM.W.TYPE2 SUM.W.TYPE6
# 1: 20    6    194   77.1         0.0         0.0        59.6
# 2: 20    2    175   63.5        74.3         0.0       136.7
# 3: 20    6    197   59.6         0.0         0.0         0.0
# 4: 20    1    185   74.3         0.0         0.0       136.7
# 5: 20    1    162   94.4        74.3        63.5       136.7
# 6: 21    1    188   58.9         0.0         0.0         0.0
# 7: 21    6    182   81.2        58.9         0.0         0.0
# 8: 21    6    169   82.8        58.9         0.0        81.2
# 9: 21    2    151   78.5        58.9         0.0       164.0
```

used `outer` function to create a comparison matrix to find out the index where there is a larger height row and subset the weight combined with the type to get the sum.

Comment: You could use `{}` in the `j` and assign `sort(unique(TYPE))` to a variable and then use the variable name instead.  That way it's only sorting once instead of twice.

Comment: I guess that doesn't help that much since you're taking the unique's first now that I think about

Answer (score 1):

Here's another data.table solution using the recently implemented `non-equi` joins feature. You'll need to grab the [development version of data.table, v1.9.7](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.7
setDT(mydata) # convert data.frame to data.table without copying

foo <- function(x, val) {
    y = x[TYPE == val]
    y[x, on = .(ID, HEIGHT > HEIGHT), 
        .(sum_val = sum(WEIGHT, na.rm = TRUE)), 
        by = .EACHI
     ][, sum_val]
}
for (type in unique(mydata$TYPE)) {
    cat("type = ", sprintf("%2.0f", type), "\n", sep="")
    mydata[, paste("sum", type, sep="_") := foo(mydata, type)][]
}
mydata
#    ID TYPE HEIGHT WEIGHT sum_6 sum_2 sum_1
# 1: 20    6    194   77.1  59.6   0.0   0.0
# 2: 20    2    175   63.5 136.7   0.0  74.3
# 3: 20    6    197   59.6   0.0   0.0   0.0
# 4: 20    1    185   74.3 136.7   0.0   0.0
# 5: 20    1    162   94.4 136.7  63.5  74.3
# 6: 21    1    188   58.9   0.0   0.0   0.0
# 7: 21    6    182   81.2   0.0   0.0  58.9
# 8: 21    6    169   82.8  81.2   0.0  58.9
# 9: 21    2    151   78.5 164.0   0.0  58.9
```

---

On the 300K row dataset from @Dean, it takes ~19s or ~1s per TYPE.

Comment: "it takes ~19s or ~1s per TYPE." --- I guess that's kinda good

Answer (score 0):

Posting my answer which was originally a comment:

```
#initializations
mydata$Sum.W.Type1 <- 0
mydata$Sum.W.Type2 <- 0
mydata$Sum.W.Type6 <- 0

#assignment
mydata[,5:7] <- 
sapply(c(1, 2, 6), function(y) 
apply(mydata, 1, 
function(x, TYPE = y) 
sum(ifelse(mydata[mydata$ID == x[1] & mydata$TYPE == TYPE,]$HEIGHT > x[3],  
mydata[mydata$ID == x[1] & mydata$TYPE == TYPE,]$WEIGHT, 0))))

mydata
  ID TYPE HEIGHT WEIGHT Sum.W.Type1 Sum.W.Type2 Sum.W.Type6
1 20    6    194   77.1         0.0         0.0        59.6
2 20    2    175   63.5        74.3         0.0       136.7
3 20    6    197   59.6         0.0         0.0         0.0
4 20    1    185   74.3         0.0         0.0       136.7
5 20    1    162   94.4        74.3        63.5       136.7
6 21    1    188   58.9         0.0         0.0         0.0
7 21    6    182   81.2        58.9         0.0         0.0
8 21    6    169   82.8        58.9         0.0        81.2
9 21    2    151   78.5        58.9         0.0       164.0
```

Depending on the scope of your data, the initializations will change as well as the number of columns requiring assignment. But, this should be good enough to get you there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach similar to @Psidom.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)
mydata_new<-mydata[,c(.SD,{ types<-(unique(TYPE));
          setNames(lapply(types, function(curtype) {
            heights<-(HEIGHT);
            sapply(heights, function(curheight) {
              sum(WEIGHT[HEIGHT>curheight & TYPE==curtype])
            })
          }),paste0('SUM.W.TYPE',types))}),by='ID']
```

The difference is that mine doesn't use `outer` which, I suspect, is a memory/performance hog.

Here's a benchmark:

```
library(data.table)
#create fake data with 300,000 rows
mydata <- data.frame(ID=rep(1:10,30000), 
                     TYPE=rep(1:20,each=15000), 
                     HEIGHT=as.integer(runif(300000,150,200)), 
                     WEIGHT=round(runif(300000,50,100),1))

setDT(mydata)

system.time({
    mydata_new<-mydata[,c(.SD,{ types<-(unique(TYPE));
              setNames(lapply(types, function(curtype) {
                heights<-(HEIGHT);
                sapply(heights, function(curheight) {
                  sum(WEIGHT[HEIGHT>curheight & TYPE==curtype])
                })
              }),paste0('SUM.W.TYPE',types))}),by='ID']
})
    #user   system  elapsed 
#1125.244    1.460 1127.665 


system.time({
  psidata<-mydata[, c(.SD, setNames(lapply(sort(unique(TYPE)), 
                                  function(type) apply(outer(HEIGHT, HEIGHT, "<"), 1, 
                                                       function(higher) sum(WEIGHT[TYPE == type & higher]))), 
                           paste0("SUM.W.TYPE", sort(unique(TYPE))))), ID]
})
    #user   system  elapsed 
#3854.596  731.272 4774.742 

all.equal(mydata_new, psidata)
#TRUE

system.time({
  frankdata<-copy(mydata)
  ut = sort(unique(mydata$TYPE))
  frankdata[order(-HEIGHT), paste0("sum_",ut) :=  lapply(ut, 
                                                         function(x) shift(cumsum( WEIGHT*(TYPE==x) ), fill=0) 
  ), by=ID]
})

   #user  system elapsed 
  #0.148   0.000   0.148
```

Frank's is by far the winner in performance.